# How do I sync my local repo with my live website, backwards and forwards? Git

Tags: linux, git, server, local

I have figured a way (using a few different tutorials) on how to push a local repo to a remote --bare repo that the uses a post-receive hook to push the contents to a live location.

So in brief explanation of my current situation

```
Make a change to a website locally
Use "git push live master"
Commit gets uploaded to remote repo
Remote repo pushes the contents to /home/unixuser/public_html
```

But say on this website there is an upload form where an admin can upload articles (on the live site), or where users can upload profile images. How would I sync my local repo with the new content in "public_html" as the repo is actually stored somewhere else on the server?

This sounds pretty simple but whenever I search for this I seem to get just the part on how to do post-receive scripts and how to upload, rather than the download part... or an over bloated explanation that leaves me confused. Is there a simplified answer to this question or am I possibly going about the whole thing the wrong way.

Any answers are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need a copy script for whenever a new file is uploaded to copy it in your repo, commit + push that.

An other solution would be to use a second repository:
git-ignore the upload directory in your current repo. use a second repo which runs  on the server, watching the upload directory - you just need to syncronize it to your local machine then. with git-ignore in the old repo, you could actually place the "upload"-repo inside the folder structure of the old repo (like it is on your server folder structure?)

Comment: With your first solution, would that be a bit crazy if there was to be 100's of uploads.. there would be lots of commits and it would be difficult to keep on top of it? But as I said I'm new to git so I may be all wrong! In your second solution, how would I "watch" the uploads directory, and make actions when it is changed as the public_html directory isn't actually a git repo... does this make sense?

Comment: git is just saving a little overhead and the changes on the files, so it would not be that crazy. of course you would maybe loose the overview over your commits, but you could structure that - commit comments + maybe using a second branch could help organizing that.

for the second solution: you could for yourself trigger a script which runs a commit on the web server for the second repository and then pull on your local machine (maybe all together in a simple script on your local machine: commit&push-trigger + git pull, should not be more that a few lines of code